# Can not install npm scoped package

Tags: npm, npm-install

My project uses private registry packages along with common packages.
I setup my scope registry according to docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope
here is config list output:

```
C:\Users\anam\Desktop\login_page>npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v8.12.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\anam\.npmrc
@infromatica:registry = "http://infamvn:8081/nexus/content/groups/npmJs_GRP/"
email = "anam@informatica.com"
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\anam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\anam\Desktop\login_page
; HOME = C:\Users\anam
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

When I try to install scoped packages I get:

```
C:\Users\anam\Desktop\login_page>npm i @informatica/archipelago-icons
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @informatica/archipelago-icons@0.0.2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-10T08_57_43_329Z-debug.log
```

here is log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   '@informatica/archipelago-icons' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose npm-session 758a10490a81bd2d
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@informatica%2farchipelago-icons 3339ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @informatica/archipelago-icons@0.0.2 404 Not Found: @informatica/archipelago-icons@0.0.2
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3589ms
11 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: @informatica/archipelago-icons@0.0.2
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\anam\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\anam\Desktop\login_page
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "@informatica/archipelago-icons"
15 verbose node v8.12.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error code E404
18 error 404 Not Found: @informatica/archipelago-icons@0.0.2
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Pay attention to line 7:

```
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@informatica%2farchipelago-icons
```

It seems like it looks for the package in the default registry instead of scoped.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the cause of the error was wrong scope naming:
@in**fro**matica:registry = "http://infamvn:8081/nexus/content/groups/npmJs_GRP/"